# Multi coin won't sync error mac osx

Tags: multibit

When i open Multibit it tries to sync then says error, unable to load block chain. I can't figure it out. Don't know what to do about it.

Comment: Was the error something along the lines of `Unable to load blockchain "***\AppData\Roaming\MultiBit\multibit.spvchain"`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thats it. But i can't navigate to the .spvchain file.

Comment: I'm on a Mac mate, i have no idea how to find files on this, nothing usually goes wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Close Multibit
- Navigate to /Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Multibit
- Rename multibit.spvchain to multibit2.spvchain
- Restart Multibit

Comment: Does this also apply to Windows where a testnet3 flag is used in the confit file? Trying to run Multibit on Testnet3 and it's not synching

Comment: I would if i was able to navigate there on my Mac.

Comment: I don't even know how to uninstall multi bit on my Mac. Multibit help is totally useless, it just sends me to a page that tells me about port numbers and then says but you don't need to worry about port numbers and thats it.

Comment: `I would if i was able to navigate there on my Mac` Have you tried this? https://www.google.com/search?q=how+do+i+open+application+support+on+mac

Comment: Thanks mate, your original answer did solve my problem, however as i said i was unable to navigate to the directory i needed as Mac Os hides the user library files, once i figured out how to see that it was fine, thank you very much.

Comment: @sdeath That's out of scope of this question. You can ask a new question about it.

Comment: Oh there it is, it turned up after all, thanks again.